# When to use cylindrical Coordinates vs rectangular

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I'm doing these two problems:

1) find the volume of the solid bounded by the graphs of the given equation:

$$ x=2 , y=x , y=0 ,  z=x^2+y^2 , z = 0 $$

2) Find the center of mass of the solid bounded by the graphs:

$$ x^2 +z^2= 4 , y = 0 , y=3  $$

iif the density at point p is directly proportional to the distance from xz-plane.

My answer key from the book uses  rectangular coordinates ( so just straight what is given). However, I was solving it using cylindrical as soon as I saw the equation of a circle in $ z = x^2 + y ^2 $  Any advice on how to differentiate when to use both systems?

Answer (score 0):

I would do both of those in cylindrical coordinates.

$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2sec\theta} r\, dr \,d\theta$

As for the second one, can't we jump to the chase and say (0,3/2,0)